# Combining two fields in a DataTextField. Is this possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dataset which I am binding to a listbox. However, I want to combine two of the fields to make up the DataTextField. Is this possible, or am I going to have to loop through the Data Rows?

```
lstAddressDropdown.DataSource = dsAddress;
lstAddressDropdown.DataTextField = "StreetAddress" + "Place";
lstAddressDropdown.DataBind();
lstAddressDropdown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
```

It's worth noting that the dataset comes back from a web service so I can't change any stored procedure to combine the columns there.

Comment: Can't you get the data in one field from your data source?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can add an additional column to the datatable that is a computed column and use it as your datatextfield (see the Microsoft Learn [Multi-field Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms810291(v=msdn.10)#multi-field-data-binding) documentation page).

So for your example above you could do something like this:

```
dsAddress.Tables[0].Columns.Add("StreetAndPlace",typeof(string),"StreetAddress + Place");
lstAddressDropdown.DataSource = dsAddress;
lstAddressDropdown.DataTextField = "StreetAndPlace";
lstAddressDropdown.DataBind();
lstAddressDropdown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
```

To add a space between the StreetAddress and Place replace the expression string shown above with `"StreetAddress + ' ' + Place"`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query as per your requirement
in Oracle

```
SELECT
'<B>'||SHORTNAME||'</B><br/>('||DEPARTMENT||')' AS USERNAME
FROM TABLE
```

In above query Name will show in bold and below it department will display
like:

```
<b>Mr. Jagdeep Mankotia</b><br>
(Web Application Development)
```

Comment: Who said anything about Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your select command and combine the 2 DataTextField you want to display.

```
DataSource.SelectCommand = "Select (Column1 || ' ' || Column2) As Column1And2 From Table";

RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "Column1And2";
```

Answer (score -1):

You never need to write loops anymore with LINQ.

- Create a class to return your two fields.

  ```
  public partial class EmployeeDropdownInfo
  {
      public int person_id { get; set; }
      public string employee_name { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Get your data and use linq to filter and return what you need.

  ```
  List<EmployeeDropdownInfo> requestors = (from t in dc.sp_GetEmployees()
  select new EmployeeDropdownInfo() 
  { 
      person_id = t.person_id, 
      employee_name = t.first_name + " " + t.last_name 
  }).ToList();

  EmployeeDropdownInfo firstEntry2 = new EmployeeDropdownInfo() { person_id = 0, employee_name = "-- Select an Employee -- " };
  requestors.Insert(0, firstEntry2);
  ddlRequestor.DataSource = requestors;
  ddlRequestor.DataTextField = "employee_name";
  ddlRequestor.DataValueField = "person_id";
  ddlRequestor.DataBind();
  ```

This way you don't have to change the procedure and dropdowns only need two values most of the time.

Comment: I wasn't using Linq to do this (back in the day). Had to be done using Datasets