# How i am able to give two strings in DataTextField of radiobuttonlist?

Tags: c#

Here "name"  and  "specification"  are fields of my tables and i want to display both that fields in the `DataTextField`. I tried upper code:

```
RadioButtonList1.DataSource = dt;
RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "name";
RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "specification";
RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
```

but it was not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining two fields in a DataTextField. Is this possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217481/combining-two-fields-in-a-datatextfield-is-this-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RadioButtonList1.Items.Clear();

foreach(var row in dt.Rows)
{
    var txt = row["name"].ToString() + " " + row["specification"].ToString();
    var val = row["id"].ToString();
    var item = new ListItem(txt,val);
    RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to populate the field on the item databound event or create a new combined column from dt;

```
var newDT = (from r in dt
             select new 
             {
                 ID = r.ID,
                 NameAndSpec = r.name + ", " + r.specification
             }
             );
```