# Multiple values on datatextfield

Tags: asp.net

I bind a dropdownlist to the datasource, and defined text and value columns on codebehind.

```
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Product_Name"
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Product_ID"
```

It works fine. But I want to assign one more column to `DataTextField`, `Order_Date`. I tried my chance with this:

```
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Product_Name"+"Order_Date"
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Product_ID"
```

But it didn't work. Is it possible to show multiple values on `DataTextField`?

Comment: I think the best way to accomplish this, is get the value complete from database.

Comment: I cannot as I have to use Linq to Entities :( it does not support most of the functions

Comment: [This Question has been already answered here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4218504/4161212

Answer (score 4):

Yes  this is possible  try by the following code:

```
var datasource = from x in products
             select new {
                 x.Id,
                 x.Code,
                 x.Description,
                 DisplayField = String.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Code, x.Description)
             };

DropDownList1.DataSource = datasource;
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DisplayField";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: No luck, it works on varchar columns but I'm trying to add a datetime column. The error is: LINQ to Entities doesn't recognize 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, best way is to get value directly from database as Freak_Droid suggested and I followed his way.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with an object `datasource` to fill the `dropdownlist` and I made a new property in the model

```
public string Datatextfield
{
    get
    {
        return Name + " - Date:  " + Date.ToShortDateString();
    }
    set { Datatextfield = value; }
}
```

And in `aspx` I use the property like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" DataSourceID="obj" runat="server" DataTextField="Datatextfield" DataValueField="ID">
```