# How to show multiple fields in combo box when using linq to sql?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, combobox

I have a database of rice types and prices. It has three fields: `fld_RiceType`, `fld_RiceId` and `fld_RicePrice`.
I want to show this database in a combobox. I used code below:

```
cmbRice.DisplayMember = "fld_RiceType";
cmbRice.ValueMember = "fld_RiceID";
cmbRice.DataSource = rnlq.tbl_Rices.OrderBy(c => c.fld_RiceType).Select(c => c);
```

I want to change `cmb.DisplayMember` to show `fld_RiceType + fld_RicePrice`.

How can I do this?

- `fld_RiceType` is `nvarchar(50)`
- `fld_RicePrice` is `varchar(50)`

Comment: WinForms ComboBox?

Comment: Yes.WinForms ComboBox.

Comment: Create an anonymous type in the Select that contains an additional property with the content of fld_RiceType + fld_RicePrice and use that property as DisplayMember.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217481/combining-two-fields-in-a-datatextfield-is-this-possible

Comment: @Ralf I think you should post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this would work but you could try something like this

```
 OrderBy(c => c.RiceType).Select(c => new { RiceId = c.RiceId, 
                                             RiceType = c.RiceType,
                                             RicePrice = c.RicePrice,
                                             DisplayValue = c.RiceType + ": " + c.RicePrice 
                                           })
```

And then ofcourse use the DisplayValue as the `DisplayMember`

Comment: please explain how to use the DisplayValue as the DisplayMember

Comment: @AbidAli i suggest you go read some linq  examples. stack overflow has some good tutorials about this.