# DropDownList needing 2 DataTextFields DataTable as DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having problems trying to give a DDL 2 DataTextFields.

```
        DataTable ServiceClonRegister = doc.getAllDataRegs(1, 999999999, "b.RegisterId=8 AND b.ACTIVE=1");
        iServiceClon.DataSource = ServiceClonRegister;
        iServiceClon.DataTextField = "Name" + "CODE";
        iServiceClon.DataValueField = "ROWID";
        iServiceClon.DataBind();
        iServiceClon.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please, pick!", "0", true));
        iServiceClon.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Any advice on how I can achieve it?
Here's the html for the element:

```
    <select class="DropDownListHint mandatory" id="iServiceClon" runat="server" aria-describedby="lbiOffice"
                                data-live-search="true" data-placement="top" data-toggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle">
                            </select>
```

Comment: not possible, you have to modify the datasource to return a merged column or add a mapping layer between - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217481/combining-two-fields-in-a-datatextfield-is-this-possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change code that fills `DataTable` in a way that query returns third column with both values. Alternatively, you can add column by yourself and put concatenated values in in. Something like this:

```
DataTable ServiceClonRegister = doc.getAllDataRegs(1, 999999999, "b.RegisterId=8 AND b.ACTIVE=1");
ServiceClonRegister.Columns.Add("NameAndCode");
foreach (DataRow row in ServiceClonRegister.Rows)
{
    row["NameAndCode"] = row["Name"].ToString() + row["CODE"].ToString();
}
iServiceClon.DataSource = ServiceClonRegister;
iServiceClon.DataTextField = "NameAndCode";
iServiceClon.DataValueField = "ROWID";
//rest of your code
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:** 
You can create an expression column & Add it to your DataTable.

```
 DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("NEwColumnName");
            dc.Expression = "Isnull(Name,'') +Isnull(Code,'')";
iServiceClon.Columns.Add(dc);
```

& use the new column in your dataTextfield. This will save you lots of loop.

**Solution 2 :** 
If the datatable is coming from an SQL query, create a virtual computed column there while selecting.